# Embed Python: Set path to executable

Tags: python, python-c-api

I would like to embed Python (in a Cocoa App under Mac OS X Mavericks). I have several Pythons installed and would like to set the one used in the App specifically. How do I do that? I tried it via `Py_SetProgramName("path/to/python")` but when I check `Py_GetProgramFullPath()` it returns something different than defined with `Py_SetProgramName()`.

Comment: You don't use the python executable when embedding Python. You just link to the correct library (.so in your case, I guess), hence it's a matter of setting the right compiler/linker switches.

Comment: @StefanNäwe And if I want to allow the user to set the python executable they want? Say they only have the system python installed, then they use that by default. If they have manually installed something else, they can specify where the executable is.

Comment: Please read again: *You don't use the python executable when embedding Python*. Period.